# Better/less verbose way to map a complex JSON response to a model using Jackson

Tags: json, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I am trying to map a complex JSON response to a domain model class using Jackson 2.  The domain model is a flattened version of the list of objects returned in the HTTP response.  Another complication is that the domain model's field names are different from the ones returned in the JSON response, to complicate things more the JSON response consists of a list of the domain model objects I am trying to map as well as other info related to the response.  Other than getting the list of domain objects from the response I also want to get some of the HTTP Response data that is not part of the array of data objects returned I managed to do this by using the readTree function and then indexing into the keys of the JSON tree.  this is quite frustrating as I have to check for null values as not all fields are aways returned.  Is there a better way to achieve what I did in the code below?  I am planning to copy this to a custom mapper class which I will then register with the Object mapper but it feels very verbose/like there should be a better way to do this other than creating DTO's that models the response?

my code:

```
var export = CxExport()
var response = mapper.readTree(body)
var count = response["response"]["count"].asInt()
export.exportCount = count
export.accountId= 123456
export.exportType = ExportType.mention
export.exportStart = Timestamp.from(Instant.now())
export.exportEnd = Timestamp.from(Instant.now())
cxExportRepo.saveAndFlush(export)

var mentions: MutableList<Mention> = ArrayList()

var data = response["response"]["data"]
data.forEach {
    println(it["permalink"]?.asText())

    var locContinent: String? = null
    var locCountry: String? = null
    var locCity: String? = null
    var locRegion: String? = null
    var locLongitude: String? = null
    var locLatitude: String? = null

    var priorityId: Int? = null
    var priorityName: String? = null
    var priorityColor: String? = null

    it["priority"]?.let {
        priorityId = it["id"]?.asInt()
        priorityColor = it["color"]?.asText()
        priorityName = it["name"]?.asText()
    }


    it["location"]?.let {
        locContinent = it["continent"]?.asText()
        locCountry = it["country"]?.asText()
        locCity = it["city"]?.asText()
        locRegion = it["region"]?.asText()
        locLongitude = it["longitude"]?.asText()
        locLatitude = it["latitude"]?.asText()

    }

    var tags: String? = null
    it["author"]["tags"]?.forEach {
        it?.asText()?.let {
            tags += it
        }
    }
    mentions.add(Mention(
            cxExport = export,
            authorId = it["author"]["id"]?.asText(),
            authorUrl = it["author"]["url"]?.asText(),
            authorImg = it["author"]["img"]?.asText(),
            authorTags = tags,
            messageTitle =it["message"]["title"]?.asText(),
            messageContent =it["message"]["content"]?.asText(),
            messageLanguage = it["message"]["language"]?.asText(),
            messageSentiment =it["message"]["sentiment"]?.asText(),
            sourceId = it["source"]["id"]?.asText(),
            sourceCategory = it["source"]["category"]?.asText(),
            sourceType = it["source"]["type"]?.asText(),
            sourceDomain = it["source"]["domain"]?.asText(),
            sourceUrl = it["source"]["url"]?.asText(),
            sourceProfile = it["source"]["profile_id"]?.asText(),
            sourceProfileName = it["source"]["profile_name"]?.asText(),
            locContinent = locContinent,
            locCountry = locCountry,
            locCity = locCity,
            locRegion = locRegion,
            locLongitude = locLongitude,
            locLatitude = locLatitude,
            permalink = it["permalink"]?.asText(),
            priorityId = priorityId,
            priorityName = priorityName,
            priorityColor = priorityColor,
            responseTime = it["timestamps"]["response_time"]?.asInt(),
            resolveTime = it["timestamps"]["resolve_time"]?.asInt(),
            handleTime = it["timestamps"]["handle_time"]?.asInt(),
            dateAdded = it["date"]["added"]?.asInt(),
            datePublished = it["date"]["published"]?.asInt()
        )
    )
}
// var response = jsonMap["response"]
// var mentions = response["data"]
mentionRepo.saveAll(mentions)
```

Comment: Consider using the `map` function instead of `forEach`.

This way you won't need to create empty lists to add elements on each iteration. Instead, each element of your json array will be mapped to a `Mention` object in a list of `mentions`.

Comment: When I test this: var data2 = response["response"]["data"].map { .. //construct mention } if I debug I get an ArrayList with the correct number of items however all the items are of type Unit and when I expand I see "No fields to display"?